# Resize image in datagridview fetch through sql query

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, image-resizing

i connected the datagridview to sql result which contain one image column my problem is when its fetch data the height of row is increased same as image height which is 1200X 800  is there any way i can resize the image column to 120X120 image is fetching directly through sql .

```
Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM studentdetail"
Dim OleDBConn1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = 
       New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cnString)
Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet()
Dim OleDbDataAdapter1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = 
     New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, OleDBConn1)

OleDBConn1.Open()
OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet1, studentdetail)
drgViewSearchData.DataSource = DataSet1.Tables(studentdetail)
OleDBConn1.Close()
drgViewSearchData.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells
```

how can i resize image column in datagridview  after fetching result . column name is "image_box"

thank you

Comment: if you dont need a fullsize image, why not resize it and save a thumbnail before the row is saved?  Otherwise, you cant resize an image using SQL, you'll have to use regular VB code.  Your example also changes the aspect ratio of the image.  1200x800 = 1.6; 120x120 = 1.0

Comment: okay .. but how can i resize through sql..  i want to stores orignal image